# Cannot connect main activity to other activities while making android navigation component

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to create navigation system between three fragments of an app, using buttons. I was following these tutorials to do that:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akuONx5RTy8

While doing so, the second and and third fragments could form connection with no problem. But upon clicking on the first fragment no any node appeared on the right side of the fragment like it did on the other fragments, because of which the first fragment couldn't connect with other fragments.

[image]

How do I connect first fragment to the second?